# Steep Diagonals and Magic Squares - Prove and State a Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, magic-square

We want to describe via a picture a set of subsets of a square which are something like
diagonals, but are not quite the same. We’ll call them steep diagonals. One of them,
labelled e, is illustrated in the square below; the other 6 are parallel to it.

[image]

State and prove a theorem about under what conditions we can expect that the sums on
the positive (or negative) steep diagonals are constant, when we’re dealing with a square
full of consecutive integers starting at 0.

A solution to this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: [1]: http://mathhelpforum.com/number-theory/147723-steep-diagonals-diabolics-interesting.html may be helpful.